# Modify row in DataTable based on two columns that are identical

Tags: c#

I have data like so:

```
Col 1 | Col 2
-------------
  a   |   9
  b   |   2
  a   |   9
  c   |   3
```

I need to remove the 9 from any duplicates of a without removing the row and keeping column 1. I added my entire DataTable to a Dictionary and was going to modify that and readd it to a new DataTable but this seems to inefficient. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you have the option to modify the query that loads the data table, or put a wrapper query around it?

Comment: So what should the output be? "Remove the 9... without removing the row" -- so you want to replace the 9 in the 3rd row with `NULL`? So row 3 should be: `a | NULL`?

Comment: The stored procedure can't be modified. And the row should simply have the value replaced with null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this I used LINQ to add only the entries that contain duplicates to a generic Dictionary. In the Dictionary, I had a value called isMarked to show it was processed. I then used a helper method to add all of the data to another DataTable and compared the unique ID column to the Dictionary. I would always add all values for the first entry that contained duplicates and then change the isMarked value to true so that no others were now added to the new DataTable.